# Cannot resolve plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.8

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, error-handling, plugins

I added below configurations but this error occurred how to solve it guys

[image]

[image]

I setup the maven configurations and also set the jdk version there, I tried several ways but couldn't resolve.